# Side menu appears only after refresh

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I want to create a mobile app with Ionic framework (my first one). I've created expense.html and expense-detail.html. The sidemenu appears correctly on the expense.html but on the "child" page it appears only after refresh. Here is my code:

This is my side-menu:

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
         <ion-header-bar class="bar-header bar-dark">
             <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
             <div class="h1 title">My Money Tracker</div>
         </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="mainContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-content></ion-content> 
    </ion-side-menu-content> 
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <a menu-close ui-sref="app.expenses" class="item">Expenses</a>
          <a menu-close ui-sref="app.incomes" class="item">Incomes</a>
          <a menu-close ui-sref="app.categories" class="item">Categories</a>
          <a menu-close ui-sref="app.statistics" class="item">Statistics</a>
          <a menu-close ui-sref="app.account" class="item">Account</a>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

These are the states of the application:

```
    .state('app.expenses', {
        url:"/expenses",
        views: {
            "mainContent" : {
                templateUrl : "app/expenses/expenses.html"
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.expense-detail', {
        url:"/expenses/:id",
        views: {
            "mainContent" : {
                templateUrl : "app/expenses/expense-detail.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

The sidemenu appears on all of app.* states by default except for app.*-detail in which it appears only after a refresh.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you testing this?
web browser, emulation or deploying it to a phone?

Comment: @JoeLloyd, I am testing this on a web browser

Comment: Should the 2nd state be defined as a child state of the first? As in: app.expenses.expense-detail?

Comment: @mrust I don't think it matters. I get to the detail page with href not ui-sref. The problem is that I get to that page, the content from expense-detail.html is shown but I get the sidemenu only after I do a refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by reading this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/ and adding enable-menu-with-back-views="true" to the side menu